# Joining explicit and implicit tables does not work - multi part identifier problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table that contains every category `description` (string), `item_condition` (int) and `loc_id_no` (int) for every date that I had some transactions going on and afterwards I want to join information from other tables about sales, reclamation's and stuff for these dates. For me it will be important to keep categories, `loc_id_no` and so on for each day even though they haven't sold anything that day.

So this is the code:

```
select 
d.record_date,
a.loc_id_no,
c.category_description_uk,
b.item_condition,
e.total_qty,
e.total_rev
from 
ai_locations a,
    (select 2 as item_condition 
    union all select 5
    union all select 7
    union all select 9) b,

    (select a.category_description_uk
    from catalog_category a) c,

    (select a.record_date 
    from txn_sales a
    where datepart(yyyy, a.record_date) = datepart(yyyy, getdate())
    group by a.record_date) d

    LEFT JOIN (
    select a.record_date, a.loc_id_no, c.category_description_uk, a.item_condition,
    sum(case when a.units > 0 then a.units else 0 end) as total_qty,
    sum(case when a.units > 0 then a.unit_net_amt else 0 end) as total_rev
    from txn_sales a
    LEFT JOIN(
        select 
            a.product_name,
            a.product_id,
            a.category_id,
            b.category_description_uk
        from 
            catalog_product a 
            LEFT JOIN(
                select 
                    a.category_id,
                    a.category_description_uk
                from 
                    catalog_category a
            ) b on a.category_id = b.category_id
    ) c on a.product_id = c.product_id
    where datepart(yyyy, a.record_date) = datepart(yyyy, getdate())
    group by a.record_date, a.loc_id_no, c.category_description_uk, a.item_condition) e on d.record_date = e.record_date AND a.loc_id_no = e.loc_id_no AND c.category_description_uk = e.category_description_uk AND b.item_condition = e.item_condition

order by 
d.record_date, a.loc_id_no, c.category_description_uk, b.item_condition
```

The error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 45 The multi-part identifier "a.loc_id_no" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 45 The multi-part identifier "c.category_description_uk" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 45 The multi-part identifier "b.item_condition" could not be bound.

Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Would be interesting which identifier could not be bound...

Comment: Ugh, mix of old and new style join syntax? Might be worth re-indenting and straightening out your use of joins to be consistent. You'll probably also find the problem while you're at it

Comment: SQL can access outer queries from inner queries. You're using the alias of "a" in at least 3 places. Try changing all the table/subquery aliases to be unique through the entire query and it "may" resolve your issue.

Comment: @stickybit 
The identifier are the following:  
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 45  
The multi-part identifier "a.loc_id_no" could not be bound.  
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 45  
The multi-part identifier "c.category_description_uk" could not be bound.  
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 45  
The multi-part identifier "b.item_condition" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a tip for resolving your issues:

```
SELECT 
  c.category_description_uk,
  s.total_qty,
  s.total_rev
FROM catalog_category c
INNER JOIN catalog_product  p
ON p.category_id = c.category_id
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT
    sum(case when s.units > 0 then s.units else 0 end) as total_qty,
    sum(case when s.units > 0 then s.unit_net_amt else 0 end) as total_rev
  FROM txn_sales s
  WHERE s.product_id  = p.product_id
    AND s.record_date >= @year_start AND s.record_date < @next_year_start
) s
WHERE ...
```